# Should one mention office launch experience in CV

Tags: resume

I work for a big retail enterprise and help the company to develop its branch in my local city. I'm in charge of office construction and launch. The office is a place for software development team. Currently, the office space is being expanded, new hardware and furniture installed, etc.

The problem is, I'm not an office launch professional. I'm a software person, actually software development project manager. So, at first sight, this experience is completely unsuitable with my résumé.

But since I'm a manager, this experience might be good to mention. It exposes my ability to communicate with different kinds of people, especially those with peculiar character. It also uncovers that I can learn things that are completely new and unusual for "tech guys".

Should I even put this line in my CV? And should I place it somewhere among unimportant things or stick it up to where the company and my employment details are described?

Answer (score 1):

> But since I'm a manager, this experience might be good to mention. It exposes my 
>   ability to communicate with different kinds of people, especially
>   those with peculiar character. It also uncovers that I can learn
>   things that are completely new and unusual for "tech guys".

When you write resume, you should tailor it to the specific job announcement. If announcement asks for someone with Management abilities, then you must place it in your CV.

> Should I even put this line in my CV? And should I place it somewhere
>   among unimportant things or stick it up to where the company and my
>   employment details are described?

If the job announcement gives more emphasis on software development, place it in the end. If it gives significant weight to management, place it in the beginning or middle.

What I would do is, list my major responsibilities, the percent of time I spent working on it, and bullet points of accomplishments, **S**ituation, **T**ask, **A**ction, **R**esult. And I'd have a section of Miscellaneous (it shows you are flexible), and list the office launch experience there.